# Broadcast/Subscribe during reroute(window.location.href) of component in angular

Tags: angular

I know that this question has been asked so many times but I have already looked at most of the answers on stackoverflow and nothing answered my question. I am trying to replicate the behavior of emit/broadcast in angular 2+ using rxjs observable. I have written an angular library and the library needs to broadcast to the users of the library(some angular 4 application) about the success/failure of an operation.I have written a broadcast service. when I am trying to broadcast from library and subscribe on the user's angular application, I always get back the initial value of the BehaviorSubject and not the latest value. I debugged it and found that during reroute(using window.location.href, it's going to an auth server and then coming back to the last angular route using window.loation.href), the component is getting recreated and broadcast service is re-instantiated and hence the broadcast previous state is lost.

I can't seem to find any way to fix this issue. Is there a way to effectively broadcast/subscribe during re-route? I am open to other suggestions to achieve the same behavior. Thank you!

Update: I have made sure that my service is singleton.I am doing everything already what @Tomasz Kula has suggested. I think I know the issue. I wasn't clear when I said rerouting. I am not rerouting within angular application. I am going to a different site(some authentication server) using window.location.href and then if login is successful, I try to set the location back to the last angular route again using window.location.href. I don't think in that case the service would be singleton.

```
My Library
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [
    ... library stuff
  ],
  exports: [
    ... library stuff
  ],
  providers: [
     ... library stuff without Broadcast Service
  ]
})
export class MyLibraryModule {
  forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyLibraryModule,
      providers: [BroadcastService]
    }
  }
}

Broadcast Service
@Injectable()
export class BroadcastService {
 private _navItemSubject : BehaviorSubject<any> ;
    private navItem$:  Observable<any>;
    constructor()
    {
     this._navItemSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(100);
     this.navItem$  = this._navItemSubject.asObservable();
    }


    broadcast(type: string ,payload: any) {
        this._navItemSubject.next({type , payload});
    }

    getNavItem()
    {
        return this.navItem$;
    }

}

Another Service in Library
@Injectable()
export class AnotherService {
 constructor(private broadcastService : BroadcastService)
{

}

// broadcasting to user's application using this method
broadcast()
{
if(success)
this.broadcastService.broadcast("success", somevalue); 
else
this.broadcastService.broadcast("error", errorDesc); 

}

}

Users can use the library like this:

in app.module

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // this will add the BroadcastService to app providers
    MyLibraryModule.forRoot()  
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {}
}


component
export class appComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 constructor(private broadcastService : BroadcastService)
{

}

  ngOnInit() {
 this.broadcastService.getNavItem().subscribe(item => {
// I get 100 here after rerouting instead of success or failure. It seems the component is recreated and broadcastservice is reinjected. Hence it has lost the state of what was already published
  alert(" listening to broadcast");
   })
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the service as an app level singleton. You can add forRoot() method to your module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [
    ... library stuff
  ],
  exports: [
    ... library stuff
  ],
  providers: [
     ... library stuff without Broadcast Service
  ]
})
export class MyLibraryModule {
  forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyLibraryModule,
      providers: [BroadcastService]
    }
  }
}
```

Users can use the library like this:

in app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // this will add the BroadcastService to app providers
    MyLibraryModule.forRoot()  
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

in any other module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    // this will add the library without the BroadcastService
    MyLibraryModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
})
export class OtherModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am already doing everything you mentioned here. The issue is that I am rerouting after authentication and component is getting recreated. The constructor of component is called again and Broadcast Service is reinjected.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. Please let me if you know what's happening.